# SFDX is not recognized as an internal or external command on VS Code

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, visualstudiocode

I'm doing some Trailhead challenges that require me to download Salesforce CLI and SF Extension Pack on VSC. I've already downloaded both (as well as Java). I've added Java and SFDX to PATH yet I keep getting these errors:

> 12:34:39.435 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias code --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
> "sfdx" is not recognized as an internal or external command

> 12:34:39.996 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias code --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
> Salesforce CLI is not installed. Install it from https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli

Here's a snapshot of my Environment Variables: [image: Environment Variables]

[image: System Variables]

I've tried everything I've seen on forums (restarting the machine and so) but it isn't working for me.

Comment: Did you try to restart vs code after installing the CLI?

Comment: Yes I did! Still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I finally fixed it!! The '\bin' in C:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI in System Variable PATH was missing.